# Redirect users based on attribute

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

Alright so what am I trying to do is that I check if user status is "pending" and if so, I'd redirect him to "/pending" page.

Now I need this check on almost the entire website.

I tried with the decision manager but was unable to redirect, any other way to do this?

This should be called only for logged users

security.yaml

```
access_decision_manager:
        service: App\Security\StatusAuthenticator
```

And the StatusAuthenticator

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;


use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManagerInterface;

class StatusAuthenticator implements AccessDecisionManagerInterface
{
    /**
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @param array $attributes
     * @param null $object
     * @return bool|void
     */
    public function decide(TokenInterface $token, array $attributes, $object = null)
    {
        if($token->getUser()->getStatus() == User::USER_STATUS_PENDING) {
            // Needs to be redirected to /pending
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to "check this on almost the entire website", you can use an `EventListener` that will fire on every request and there you can check if you have an authenticated user and their status.

```
// src/EventListener/PendingUserListener.php
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class PendingUserListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private $security;

    /**
     * @var UrlGeneratorInterface
     */
    private $urlGenerator;    

    public function __construct(Security $security, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [ KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onKernelRequest' ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $pending_route = 'pending';
        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return;
        }

        // Check if the requested page is 'pending', prevent redirect loops
        if ($pending_route === $event->getRequest()->get('_route')) {
            return;
        }

        // RedirectResponse expects a full url, generate from route name
        if (User::USER_STATUS_PENDING == $user->getStatus()) {
            $event->setResponse(
                new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate($pending_route))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose this could go as a good thing. What I went next to this is having a StatusCheckerVoter that eventually returns boolean, and then I handle errors with AcessDeniedHandler

Comment: @TomislavTomiNikolic The voter should be pretty straightforward to create, but you lost me with denying access, I thought you wanted to redirect? Still, _should_ be doable with `access_control`.

Comment: Well the thing I'm doing is that I'm having a voter that decides if you should see the page or not, then if not access denied is triggered. Then I'm having access denied script that does the redirections. Its complicated, I have to rethink the entire system, but what you added here is waaay better!